# php mysql form input type

Tags: php, mysql

I want a table that can submit value
I try with form

my problem is text is editable I look for input type that can only read but can not edit
I want a table that only some column can edit then can send what should i do

Comment: me no can we be more like sometimes understand yeah.

Comment: reword your question please, and if possible show some code.

Comment: whats the point of a non editable form input in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for a read-only form field in HTML (e.g. in your PHP file) use this:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly"/>
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This will make the field readonly for your users.